# Inssue with 'transform.forward" unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make some point forward of my player camera, the problem is the point isn't forward of my camera, is very crooked.

Here it's clear the diference of the point to the camera forward.

[image]

[image]

I realy don't know what is causing this problem.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You are treating a **direction** as if it was a **position**

instead of

```
aimargetInstantiate.transform.position = cameraHolderObj.transform.forward * 10;
```

you rather want to use

```
aimargetInstantiate.transform.position = cameraHolderObj.transform.position + cameraHolderObj.transform.forward * 10;
```

---

Btw side note: To make your code a bit shorter and easier to maintain you can use

```
aimLayerAnimator.SetBool("IsAiming", isAiming);
```

and same in

```
isAiming = Input.GetKey(aimingKey);
```

;)